# Получение метрик интернета

Tags: java, android

Нужно получить метрики для подключенного в данный момент на телефоне интернета, таких как входящая и исходящая скорость и количество потерянных пакетов. С помощью чего это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно например сделать таким образом:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkCapabilities nc = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
var downSpeed = nc.getLinkDownstreamBandwidthKbps();
var upSpeed = nc.getLinkUpstreamBandwidthKbps();
```

Получить уровень `WiFi`:

```
public int getWifiLevel()
{
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int linkSpeed = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
    int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(linkSpeed, 5);
    return level;
}
```

[Вот](https://android.jlelse.eu/designing-android-apps-to-handle-slow-network-speed-dedc04119aac) есть статья по данному вопросу и [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159487/android-how-to-determine-network-speed-in-android-programmatically) такого же плана.